# How to determine what Ruby-on-Rails code generated some SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an application written in Ruby using Rails 2.3. We use ActiveRecord.

Occasionally, ActiveRecord generates some pretty hideously inefficient SQL. We can determine what SQL is problematic using slow-query logs and using [new relic](http://newrelic.com/). However, it can be really difficult to determine the line of code in our software that generated the problematic SQL. It's generally a query built up using associations and named_scopes.

What I'd really like is some way to tag the SQL in our log files with the filename and line of **our** code that generated it (not the line of ActiveRecord that executed the query).

The information should be available via the caller array. I don't want to dump the entire array, I just want the filename and line of our code most directly responsible. Is there a gem which already does this? If not, any suggestions?

Comment: A co-worker suggested that we place the filename and line number (once we determine WHAT those are) in the SQL itself as a comment, rather than just putting it in the regular production log file. That way, the slow query log would also have this information.

Answer (score 5):

you should find some inspiration along the [active-record-query-trace](https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace) gem

**EDIT:** wooops, read it too fast, this is for RoR 3+. [>This< seems to work for rails 2.3](https://github.com/ntalbott/query_trace). You may also find some inspiration **[here](http://gurge.com/blog/2006/11/09/rails-sql-logging-improvements/)**.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for reference to the Rails 3 gem. It's odd this isn't more people who need this ...

Answer (score 1):

[rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby) does include information on which line of ruby code generated which sql query.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic will give you full stack traces for individual slow SQL queries with the [Slow SQL](http://newrelic.com/docs/features/slow-sql) and Transaction Traces features.